# Is there a way to see video after applying packet loss

Tags: video-processing, video, forward-error-correction

I have encoded a video stream using JM using RTP. Then i have applied rtp_loss on it but after that i am unable to decode video. [Like in this example](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~belyaev/football.gif) a video with different packet loss percentages are depicted. I want to apply packet loss on H.264 RTP stream than want to decode it. But whenever i want to decode using JM it is unable to handle it. I have heard that [Netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) could be an option but i am not using Linux. So Is there a way to apply packet loss on video and than see how  video quality is changed after it like in the example link given above?